# C# MVC - RedirectToAction method encode query parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, url-encoding

I am to trying to redirect to an action method from another action method using the `RedirectToAction` MVC method. The destination action method accepts a query param. When I call the destination method, the query param gets Url encoded.

The destination method has following signature:

```
[Route("\resource\{id}")]
public ActionResult DestMethod(int id, string token)
```

I call this method using RedirectToAction from another action method like below

```
RedirectToAction("DestMethod", new {id = id, token = token});
```

So when the control enters the DestMethod the token parameter gets Url Encoded.

What is the reason for this behavior and how to prevent it?

EDIT:

If I am sending token parameter as is i.e. without Url Encoding, from `RidirectToAction`, the `DestMethod` is receiving it as encoded and does not decode it. This is the behavior that is confusing. Everything works well if I sent encoded parameter from jquery ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Url Encoding is needed to ensure that the address is correct according to the standard ([Uniform Resource Identifier (URI)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) seems to be the one). If the parameter was not encoded, there is no guarantee that the browsers would act correctly and the redirection actually contain the entire token parameter.

As MVC should automatically decode the incoming, encoding the outgoing parameter should be the wanted behaviour in all normal cases. The only case I can think of where this is not wanted is if the token already is URL-encoded when I would suggest you to decode the token before using it in RedirectToAction.

Comment: If I am sending token parameter as is i.e. without Url Encoding, from `RidirectToAction`, the `DestMethod` is receiving it as encoded and does not decode it. This is the behavior that is confusing. Everything works well if I sent encoded parameter from jquery ajax. I have added an edit to the question regarding the same

Comment: According to my understanding, it seems like it is the route that is making this not decode properly, see https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4599